# Are there specific properties defining the kernel of a quotient ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, polynomial-rings

I'm asking because the correction of an exercise of a course I'm following (commutative algebra) has the following conclusion:

---

**Let I be an ideal of a commutative ring A, and $I[X]=\{\sum_{k=0}^{n}i_{k}X^{k}\mid i_{k}\in I\}\subseteq A[X]$ ideal in A[X]. Show that A[X]/I[X] is isomorphic to the ring (A/I)[X].**

Let $\pi_{I}:A\rightarrow A/I$ be the natural application$^{(1)}$ and $\phi:A[X]\rightarrow(A/I)[X]\ :\ \sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}X^{k}\mapsto\sum_{k=0}^{n}\pi_{I}(a_{k})X^{k}$.

$\phi$ is a surjective morphism and $\ker(\phi)=I[X]$.

$\Rightarrow$ $I[X]\subseteq \ker(\phi)$ therefore by the universal quotient property there exists a natural$^{(1)}$ isomorphism $f:A[X]/I[X]\rightarrow(A/I)[X]$.

---

The part which causes me trouble is:

> and $\ker(\phi)=I[X]$

I'm wondering where that conclusion comes from; if it is a general property of quotient rings or if it actually comes from that specific space's structure, if it comes from that space's structure **in particular**.

(1) translated from french: "application canonique", maybe canonical? I am unsure.

Comment: First of all these are quotient **rings**, not spaces. Second, do you conclude from $\ker\phi=I[X]$ that $I[X]\subseteq\ker\phi$??? Last but not least, if one knows that $\ker\phi=I[X]$ why don't use the fundamental theorem of isomorphism for rings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement $\ker\phi=I[X]$ is specific to this problem, and it is immediate:

A polynomial $p(X)=\sum_{i\le k}a_iX^i$ is in the kernel of $\phi$, by definition, iff $\phi(p)=0$, iff each coefficient of $\phi(p)$ is zero, iff each $\pi_I(a_i)=0$ by definition of $\phi$.
But $\pi_I(a_i)=0\in A/I$ means exactly $a_i\in I$.

So we get that $p\in\ker\phi\iff\forall i:a_i\in I\iff p\in I[X]$.

Comment: This clears things up, I think what confused me is that the kernel of that quotient space used neutral elements, but I only thought about neutral elements in multiplication, not addition. I was wrong from the very beginning on that, it is now obvious that there is a relationship between kernels and additive neutral elements.